# Automatically updating data from an API to an SQL database?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pandas

I have data coming from an API in JSON format which I then run a few functions/transformations in python and then insert the data in to an SQL database through pandas & SQLalchemy.

Now, how do I automatically do this at the end of every day, without having to open up the script and run it manually?

Comment: Supposing this script runs on a server, what about using a crontab? i.e. put the script to run daily at 23:00hrs (0 23 * * *)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`crontab`](https://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference) on a server (or your Linux/Mac laptop but it will not run the script if its turned off of course).

You can run `crontab -e` to edit the crontab file. Add something like the following to run your script everyday at 11 PM:

```
0 23 * * * ~/myscript.py
```

[crontab guru](https://crontab.guru/#0_23_*_*_*) is a useful resource to try different schedule expressions.